# Keyword Search Query: Document Name versus Title

Tags: search, keywordquery

We have an SP2010 system running ordinary enterprise search.

I have an issue with contains queries using the Title managed property and another managed property called Filename.

What happens is when you do a contains query the Title query fails to recognize underscores whereas a contains query using the filename property correctly retrieves documents. *I should point out we have an event handler that makes the title field the same as the document name field.* So if a user saves a document name with underscores the same name is automatically replicated to the title field.

I would have thought if a system recognises underscores as a stop character then this would be consistent across the board. Anybody have ideas on what might be causing this discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Some properties use word breakers and some dont. I think Title is one of them.

If the word breaker is a problem for you, you can implement your own:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163981(v=office.15).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693186(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri: my answer is an actual answer, but I added a possible solution.

Comment: I guess better now, previously it looked like a comment :)